# JSON array .length property not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON array:

```
[  
   {  
      "orderStatus":"S",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiable":"N",
      "grandTotal":"24",
      "orderId":"",
      "grandTotalCurrency":"USD",
      "placedDate":"2015-05-11T17:56:27.406Z",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiableUntil":"2012-07-24 23:59:00.0",
      "externalOrderID":"29001e"
   },
   {  
      "orderStatus":"S",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiable":"N",
      "grandTotal":"23",
      "orderId":"",
      "grandTotalCurrency":"USD",
      "placedDate":"2015-04-11T17:56:27.406Z",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiableUntil":"2012-07-24 23:59:00.0",
      "externalOrderID":"29001d"
   },
   {  
      "orderStatus":"S",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiable":"N",
      "grandTotal":"22",
      "orderId":"",
      "grandTotalCurrency":"USD",
      "placedDate":"2015-03-11T17:56:27.406Z",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiableUntil":"2012-07-24 23:59:00.0",
      "externalOrderID":"29001c"
   }
]
```

This array is named "OrderStatusArray".  I'm trying to get the length of the array without hardcoding it (for obvious reasons), but I cannot figure out how to do it.  I've seen a dozen posts on SO saying that I should just be able to do OrderStatusArray.length to get the length of the array, but that isn't working for me.

How do I get the length of this array?

Comment: Where’s your code? What does "but that isn't working for me" mean? Do you see any error?

Comment: As all say, with .length: http://jsfiddle.net/203w81Lk/

Comment: works for me. maybe you are using some ancient browser?

Comment: @idmean my code is simply ${ allOrdersInThisCategory.length }, and I don't see anything.  If I just print the array, it prints fine to the screen.  If I go to print the length, nothing gets printed.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have an array?  You said you have a "JSON array", which is not a real thing.  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  Do you have an array or do you have a JSON string?

Comment: What kind of JavaScript syntax is `${ allOrdersInThisCategory }`? Where do you use that?

Comment: @idmean: Looks like some sort of templating engine.

Comment: @idmean Websphere commerce... the bane of my existence.

Comment: But Websphere commerce is Java, isn’t it? And in this piece of code you showed us doesn’t use `.length`. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @idmean It uses JSPs and JSTL with embedded javascript on this particular jsp

Comment: @jros: What does the source of your page look like?  What is the *actual* JavaScript code the browser is running?  Is `${ allOrdersInThisCategory.length }` being processed by JavaScript or the server?

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x983vvr6/2/

Essentially, assuming you have correctly set up the object you simply need to call

```
OrderStatusArray.length
```

And it will display the length of the array.

What length are you expecting? 3 is the correct answer and the answer which this fiddle shows.

Full code:

```
var OrderStatusArray = [{
"orderStatus": "S",
    "x_ExtnIsModifiable": "N",
    "grandTotal": "24",
    "orderId": "",
    "grandTotalCurrency": "USD",
    "placedDate": "2015-05-11T17:56:27.406Z",
    "x_ExtnIsModifiableUntil": "2012-07-24 23:59:00.0",
    "externalOrderID": "29001e"
  }, {
"orderStatus": "S",
    "x_ExtnIsModifiable": "N",
    "grandTotal": "23",
    "orderId": "",
    "grandTotalCurrency": "USD",
    "placedDate": "2015-04-11T17:56:27.406Z",
    "x_ExtnIsModifiableUntil": "2012-07-24 23:59:00.0",
    "externalOrderID": "29001d"
   }, {
"orderStatus": "S",
    "x_ExtnIsModifiable": "N",
    "grandTotal": "22",
    "orderId": "",
    "grandTotalCurrency": "USD",
    "placedDate": "2015-03-11T17:56:27.406Z",
    "x_ExtnIsModifiableUntil": "2012-07-24 23:59:00.0",
    "externalOrderID": "29001c"
     }];


console.log("Your order length array is: " + OrderStatusArray.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = [  
   {  
      "orderStatus":"S",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiable":"N",
      "grandTotal":"24",
      "orderId":"",
      "grandTotalCurrency":"USD",
      "placedDate":"2015-05-11T17:56:27.406Z",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiableUntil":"2012-07-24 23:59:00.0",
      "externalOrderID":"29001e"
   },
   {  
      "orderStatus":"S",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiable":"N",
      "grandTotal":"23",
      "orderId":"",
      "grandTotalCurrency":"USD",
      "placedDate":"2015-04-11T17:56:27.406Z",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiableUntil":"2012-07-24 23:59:00.0",
      "externalOrderID":"29001d"
   },
   {  
      "orderStatus":"S",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiable":"N",
      "grandTotal":"22",
      "orderId":"",
      "grandTotalCurrency":"USD",
      "placedDate":"2015-03-11T17:56:27.406Z",
      "x_ExtnIsModifiableUntil":"2012-07-24 23:59:00.0",
      "externalOrderID":"29001c"
   }
];
console.log( data.length );
```

do you want this?